# This place is like a labyrinth

Tags: word-usage

Let's say me and my friends are in a car and we are in a gritty neighborhood in which it is hard to find your way. It is like a maze. There are so many streets/alleys and it has no proper signs etc., and we can't find the way out of that place. Is it fine to say one of these?

- This place is a labyrinth.
- This place is like a labyrinth.

I am asking this because I am used to seeing "of" after "labyrinth" in sentences like, "This place is like a labyrinth of roads," "His house is like a labyrinth of passages" etc. My sentences don't have "of..." after "labyrinth." Are my sentences all right?

Answer (score 4):

This place is a labyrinth. [**metaphor or image**]

This place is like a labyrinth. [**a simile, a comparison using like or as.**]

Both are possible. Your choice.

"He's like a big bear".

"He is a big bear."

Reference: internalized knowledge

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20like%20a%20labyrinth%22&sxsrf=ALeKk03t7u-Vjo4eMdsnzAzwQxqi0Hkd8A%3A1626445101552&ei=LZXxYN39IJPAlAam6Kq4Bg&oq=%22is%20like%20a%20labyrinth%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAxKBAhBGABQAFgAYOvYAWgAcAJ4AIAB7QSIAe0EkgEDNS0xmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwidyJiU5OfxAhUTIMUKHSa0CmcQ4dUDCA0) gives more than three million hits of ***is like a labyrinth*** as the end of a sentence. And even though it is mostly used metaphorically like for example

> Life is like a labyrinth

or

> the mind of man is like a labyrinth

You can rest assured, your comparison works very well in a more literal sense.